# jQuery UI Droppable accept condition with form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to make a draggable item to drop onto a droppable zone. However, I would like to display a form to input information and store in the database. When the information is stored then the droppable is successful, otherwise revert the item back.

Here is [the jsFiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/QKMNg/4/) to demonstrate.

Here is the piece of code I am having trouble with:

```
$("#taskClosed").droppable({
  accept: function(el) {
    console.info(el.parent().parent().attr("id"));
    if ((el.parent().parent().attr("id") == "wrapper_taskAssigned") &&
      (el.position().left > $("#taskAssigned").width())) {
      if (closeTask(el) == true) return true;
      // need some improvement here
    }
    return false;
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    // will perform drop item
  }
});
// handle the task close event
function closeTask(el) {
  $("#taskcloseForm-header").empty().append("Close task  " + el.data("name"));
  $("#popupCloseTask").popup("open");
}
```

I would like to be able to move Task 2 to Closed Task column, which will pop up a form to enter information. After submission, the form will call another function to perform an Ajax post to the backend controller.

I would like to make the stickynote to revert back if the user clicks on cancel, or the submission failed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/QKMNg/7/)**

This function was not defined `closeTask(el)`,

```
if ((el.parent().parent().attr("id") == "wrapper_taskAssigned") &&
      (el.position().left > $("#taskAssigned").width())) {
      if (closeTask(el) == true) return true;   // this function was not defined
      // need some improvement here
    }
    return false;
```

I have removed it ,just to make the popup work

Add this code for form submit using ajax and to restore draggable to original position on cancel button click

```
       /** get the original position of draggable**/
    $("li[id='draggable']").data("Left", $("li[id='draggable']").position().left)
        .data("Top", $("li[id='draggable']").position().top);

       /** ajax form submit**/
    $("#closetaskForm-submit-button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',  // change the url 
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('succes');
            }
        });

    });
             /** restore draggable to original position**/
    $("#closetaskForm-cancel-button").click(function () {
    $("#popupCloseTask").popup("close");
    $("li[id='draggable']").animate(
                { "left": $("li[id='draggable']").data("Left"), 
                    "top": $("li[id='draggable']").data("Top")
                }, "slow");
    });

          /**avoid popup closing on outside popup click**/
$("#popupCloseTask").on({
    popupbeforeposition: function () {
        $('.ui-popup-screen').off();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you